# Localhost Websocket Events Don't Work With Truffle?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, truffle, ethers.js, websocket

I created a simple smart contract that emits an event when a function in called.

When I run it with `truffle develop` it says "Truffle Develop started at [http://127.0.0.1:9545/"](http://127.0.0.1:9545/%22)

I then start up a node.js script that connects to it with websocket connection via ethers.js, something like this:

```
...

new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider('ws://localhost:9545')

...


const contract = new ethers.Contract(
  contractAddress,
  contractAbi,
  signer
)

contract.on('GuessSubmitted', async (param1, param2) => {

  console.log('Got an event!');

})
```

This seems to connect alright to the contract (when I put in any other url it blows up with errors, but with this it doesn't...).

The problem is that when the "GuesSubmitted" event is emitted from my locally running smart contract it is never heard by my event listener here...

Is there some issue with locally running truffle projects that events don't work? Or I am just doing something wrong? Is this a limitation for all ethereum projects (eg hardhat as well) or just truffle?